# How can i customize a field when i am making a pull request in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Below is a code that deletes a sub document inside **roomTypes** field and it works fine. The problem is that i want to reuse the code instead of writting one. This because apart from having a field **roomTypes** with sub documents i also have other fields with sub documents. so i would like to write one code that i can use to update them. 
So under the field that is being pulled is there way i can use something like a template string the way i have done for { _id: `${req.params.position}` } so that i can update a field based on what is coming in the request body. In short i do not want to hard code the **roomTypes** field. I want it to be dynamic based on what is coming from the request body. Please help on this

```
exports.deleteRoomType = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const reqHostel = await Hostel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
    $pull: {
      roomTypes: { _id: `${req.params.position}` }
    }
  });
  //   process.exit();
  res.status(204).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: null
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass another paramer `fieldName` and build your update expression based on that field's value:

```
const reqHostel = await Hostel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
    $pull: {
        [req.params.fieldName]: { _id: `${req.params.position}` }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer let me give it a try then i will give you feedback